# Does working other muscles improve recovery?

Tags: workout, recovery, muscle-mass, muscle-recovery, recovery-heart-rate

When you work out `muscle group A` on one day, and `muscle group B` on another day, does `muscle group A` benefit from the second workout?  I don't mean overlap (e.g., working nearby muscle groups).  Rather, I'm wondering if things like raising your heart rate when working `muscle group B` help improve your recovery for `muscle group A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a study floating around that shows muscle increases simply from taking anabolic steroids, with no additional workload. So one would imagine that if you did something to yourself that increased your testosterone and human growth hormone, and had enough protein, you'd get (minute but) similar results.

I don't know if there's any research specifically addressing your question though, and I'd imagine the resulting increases would be *very* small.

Comment: The problem here is that workouts raise your testosterone but also exhaust your body. So it stands to reason that working out, while possibly having an effect on other muscle groups, could also negatively impact their ability to recover by overstressing the body itself. This is just a thought, I could be totally off base (haven't looked at any research).